# Tomcat -Djava.library.path set

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to point a `-Djava.library.path` in `setenv.sh` file. My library is in `usr/lib64` folder but when I am trying to do something like :

`EXPORTS JAVA_OPTS="-Dcom.site.host=site.com -Dcom.site.storage.path=/usr/hosting/site.com/db -Dcom.site.lib=/usr/lib64/mylib.so"`

I am getting :

```
error : Directory separator should not appear in library name : /usr/lib64/mylib.so
```

How to set it correctly?

`mylib.so` is already present in `usr/lib64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an new variable for java path where exist native library or copy paste your native library to default java.path.

set environment variables as follows

Edit the system Path file /etc/profile

```
sudo gedit /etc/profile
```

Add following lines in end

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export JAVA_HOME
export JRE_HOME
export PATH
```

Finaly set VMOption: `-Djava.library.path="path_to_native_library"`

Answer (score 1):

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="usr/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

Now run your Java program.